# Selenium JSON file asserting

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to validate correct JSON file sent to the Azure Cosmos database from my UI. The fact is that I'm using simple database connection and then I'm comparing each field using Assert.AreEqual (NUnit).

```
        private void SuccessfulPaymentByCardDatabaseDataCheck()
        {
            using (ICosmosDbRepository repository = new CosmosDbRepository())
            {
                var document = repository.GetLastDocument("Orders", Configuration.CosmosDbName);

                Assert.AreEqual("PaymentTerminal", document.payments[0].type.ToString());
                Assert.AreEqual("Mastercard", document.payments[0].name.ToString());
                Assert.AreEqual("Accepted", document.payments[0].result.ToString());
                Assert.AreEqual(3.5, (decimal)document.payments[0].amount);
                Assert.AreEqual(0, (decimal)document.payments[0].rounding);
                Assert.AreEqual(0, (decimal)document.payments[0].cashback);

                Assert.AreEqual(taxPercent, decimal.Parse(document.vats[0].percent.ToString()));
                Assert.AreEqual(latteProductPrice, (decimal)document.vats[0].total);
                Assert.AreEqual(CountTax(3.5M, taxPercent), (decimal)document.vats[0].totalTax);
                Assert.AreEqual(3.5M - CountTax(3.5M, taxPercent), (decimal)document.vats[0].totalWithoutTax);

                Assert.AreEqual(3.5, decimal.Parse(document.total.ToString()));
                Assert.AreEqual(0.0, decimal.Parse(document.totalDiscounts.ToString()));

                Assert.AreEqual(1, (decimal)document.rows[0].quantity);
                Assert.AreEqual(0, (decimal)document.rows[0].orderNumber);
                Assert.AreEqual(latteProductPrice, (decimal)document.rows[0].total);
                Assert.AreEqual(CountTax(3.5M, taxPercent), (decimal)document.rows[0].totalTax);
                Assert.AreEqual("pcs", document.rows[0].unit.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to do it in more effective way? For example by downloading the whole json from the query and then comparing it with default one (created before)?

Comment: Personally, I think your current implementation is fine, the test result will be less meaningful when it fails on the full json document.

Comment: Why is this tagged Selenium when there's no Selenium code here?